# No view found for id for fragment in Preference setting screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, application-settings

In my application I use DraverLayout as a main activity, which contains fragments as a parts of navigationView.
But for settings I use SettingActivity which contains SettingFragment. Problem appears when I try to open subscreen from settings screen:
**"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09014e (com.example.tipcollector:id/settings_container) for fragment NotificationMenuFragment{1fe50ef} (618cc8dc-6287-4830-b9a1-0e9b2d1d1827) id=0x7f09014e}"**. What was done incorrectly and how can i fix it? I will appreciate any help or information!

**SettingActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tipcollector;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.tipcollector.Notification.NotificationMenuFragment;
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback {
    private Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(findViewById(R.id.settings_container)!=null){
            if(savedInstanceState!=null)
                return;
             getSupportFragmentManager()
                     .beginTransaction()
                     .replace(R.id.settings_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        }




        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceStartFragment(PreferenceFragmentCompat caller, Preference pref) {
        final Bundle args = pref.getExtras();
        final Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentFactory().instantiate(
                getClassLoader(),
                pref.getFragment());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.setTargetFragment(caller,0);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }


}
```

**Here is my SettingsFragment**

```
package com.example.tipcollector;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;
import androidx.preference.ListPreference;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;
import com.example.tipcollector.Notification.NotificationMenuFragment;
import database.DataBaseHelper;


public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements PreferenceManager.OnPreferenceTreeClickListener {



    public static final String PREF_HOURLY_RATE = "hourly_rate_key";
    public static final String PREF_CURRENCY = "currencies";
    public static final String PREF_NOTIFICATION = "notifications";

    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference) {
        String key = preference.getKey();

        if ("clear_all_key".equals(key)) {}

        if(PREF_NOTIFICATION.equals(key)){
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings_container,new NotificationMenuFragment()).commit();   

        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencesscreen,rootKey);

        preferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

                if(key.equals(PREF_HOURLY_RATE)){
                    EditTextPreference hourlyRatePref = findPreference(key);
                    hourlyRatePref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key,""));
                }else if(key.equals(PREF_CURRENCY)){
                    ListPreference currencyPref = findPreference(key);
                    currencyPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key,""));
                }

            }
        };
    }
```

**And xml files for both. Here is preference screen (layout for SettingFragment)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/setting_general"
        />
        <ListPreference
            android:entryValues="@array/currencies"
            android:entries="@array/currencies"
            app:title="@string/select_currency"
            app:key="currencies"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_money_black"
            android:defaultValue="PLN"/>
        <EditTextPreference
            android:summary="@string/settings_general_hourly_rate"
            android:title="@string/your_hourly_rate"
            app:key="hourly_rate_key"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_business_center_black_24dp"
            />
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/data_settings"/>
        <Preference
            android:title="@string/clear_all_database"
            app:key="clear_all_key"
            android:summary="@string/clear_all_data_message"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_black_24dp"/>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Notification"/>

        <Preference
            android:title="Notification"
            app:key="notification"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"/>
    
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**And here is SettingActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/settings_container"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I noticed that replace is being called on the FrameLayout container settings_container both via: getChildFragmentManager() and getSupportFragmentManager(). Could that be the problem?

Comment: I've used getSupportFragmentManager() to make transaction from activity to fragment, and in SettingsFragment im trying to reach another fragment so that's why getChildFrragmentManager() there

Comment: Wait, where in the code are you inflating the SettingsFragment layout? Also show the code for SettingsFragment layout

Comment: @Sarah my SettingFragment i use as preference screen so layout for fragment appear in this line      
setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencesscreen,rootKey);

Comment: Okay. 1) You have defined PREF_NOTIFICATION = "notifications"; but there is no key called notifications in your preferencesscreen. 2) There is no layout defined in prefrencesscreen.xml which has id = settings_container so it will throw error

Comment: @Sarah I agree with you. But.. I use ActivitySetting which is actualy empty activity, with container for my setting fragment (preference screen).I found information for settings screens  and it says that .   1)create Activity with container.  2) Implement PreferenceFragmentCompat to this container. At this moment everything was okey but when i decided to add subscreens, which is also PreferenceFragmentCompat, i got stuck. I must find out how to change settingFragment in container by anothe PreferenceFragmentCompat . Some information is here

Comment: @Sarah https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS9jhuHECEQ&t=563s&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to be done in your preferencesscreen.xml

```
<Preference
            android:title="Notification"
            app:key="notification"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
            app:fragment="com.example.tipcollector.Notification.NotificationMenuFragment" />
```

Also, remove this method from your SettingsFragment

```
@Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference) {
        String key = preference.getKey();

        if ("clear_all_key".equals(key)) {}

        if(PREF_NOTIFICATION.equals(key)){
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings_container,new NotificationMenuFragment()).commit();   

        }

        return true;
    }
```

You don't need this since preferenceClick will be handled by this tag in xml

```
app:fragment="com.example.tipcollector.Notification.NotificationMenuFragment"
```

Comment: Okey. Thank you very much it finally worked for me. As i understand my subscree wasn't opening because **public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference)** Method bloked somehow my transaction in XML. Thank you very much again